# What type of problem is solving 1 treasure in 1000 boxes?

Tags: combinatorics, stochastic-processes, dynamic-programming

Is the following problem a dynamic programming problem or some other type like stochastic optimization ?

> You have 1000 boxes and only 1 box contains the "treasure". In order
>   to find the correct box, you must line the boxes up 1-1000 and
>   systematically remove one box, save the next box, remove the next box,
>   etc, etc. What number box contains the treasure?

Comment: Are the boxes identical? Do you get to choose the order or is it preconditioned? Do you have to start with box 1?

Comment: The question reminds me a bit of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem

Comment: I don't understand the question.  The treasure box is not determined by your search algorithm, it could be any of them.  Can you clarify?  Perhaps show us what you mean with a smaller number, like five boxes.

Comment: @lulu that's my thought. If the boxes are identical and the treasure is hidden in a random box, there is no algorithm which will perform better than guessing.

Comment: @ALB  exactly.  I expect the OP means to put the numbers in a circle and is asking which will be the last number chosen, something like that...though that's a big reach from what is written.

Comment: This seems to be one of those creative-thinking job interview questions.  See https://www.reddit.com/r/puzzles/comments/3oy66n/puzzle_given_during_a_job_interview/ for example.  It strikes me as rather vaguely worded, though.

Comment: @lulu, based on the solutions advanced at the link I found (which presents the problem in the exact same fashion as the OP here, down to the comma in "etc, etc."), it does seem to mean *line*, not *circle*, with the (unstated!) rule that when you reach the end of the line you start over again with the line of "saved" boxes, removing the first, saving the next, etc, etc.

Comment: @BarryCipra  Ah, thanks.  Those solutions make complete sense if you add a whole bunch of unstated rules, which as a job candidate would truly irritate me.

Comment: @lulu, I'd be irritated too if an interviewer posed such a question.  Of course, what we might be seeing in the source I found is an applicant's remembered version of a question that was cogently posed.